# How to trigger $('.button-collapse').sideNav('hide'); in vuejs 2 without jQuery?

Tags: vue.js, materialize, vuejs2

I have successfully added the following code which provides me with the sideNav from materialise:

```
<v-btn-link v-side-nav:side-nav="nav" class="button-collapse btn-flat" id="btn-side-menu"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></v-btn-link>
<v-side-nav id="side-nav" class="hide-on-small">
  <a v-on:click="handleNavDashboard()">Dashboard</a>
  <a v-on:click="handleLogout()">Logout</a>
</v-side-nav>
```

and I use the following methods:

```
  methods: {
    handleLogout () {
      console.log('LOGGED OUT')
      this.$store.dispatch('clearAuthUser')
      window.localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
      this.$router.push({name: 'login'})
    },
    handleNavDashboard () {
      console.log('GOING DASHBOARD')
      console.log(this)
      this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
    }
  }
```

so when I am on the home page and i click Dashboard, I get the dashboard contents on the screen but the sideNav menu and the darkened background are still there. Materialise-css says you can use this function

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav('hide');
```

to hide it progmatically but I don't have jQuery installed. How to I reset the sideNav after a nav click?

Comment: It seems like materialize-css depends on jquery

Comment: You may find the `Vue` version useful: http://johnleider.com/vue-materials-docs/

Comment: @craig_h It is that version that I am using. I am also trying other SO answers to get jQuery working in my app but no luck there either.

Comment: @khany Are you using `npm`, it looks like you will need to load `jQuery` globally, is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @craig_h Yes I am using `npm`. How do i make jQuery global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CDN**

From Materialize docs:

> One last thing to note is that you have to import jQuery before
>   importing materialize.js!

```
<body>
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**NPM**

Much better way, install jQuery via npm :

```
npm install jquery
```

and use webpack [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin) to make jQuery global module available in all of your files
here is sample of [webpack.config.js](https://jsfiddle.net/ppmfahd6/) file

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```

**In Vue.js DOM manipulations are encapsulated inside directives**, you can use conditional rendering directives `v-if` or `v-show` to make this work without using jquery:

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yd8weph7/1/)

---

Also check component framework [Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/) that provide clean, semantic and reusable components.

Comment: @t-dom93 genius! Never thought to write my own side-nav, but now I have. It's crude but does the job. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: Glad to help you! Please consider to accept answer if it was helpful for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include `jQuery` in to a project which is using `requires` or `imports`, then you need to make sure it's `required` and not included using `script` tags, because it will be outside the scope of the compiled code (unless it was shimmed), so add the following to your project:

**ES6 syntax:**

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery
```

**ES5 Syntax:**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

And make sure you have installed jQuery:

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

This puts `jQuery` into the global scope so it can be used site wide. The docs for that package don't really make that clear, and for some reason they don't mention that `jQuery` is a dependency, but looking at the code it clearly is for some of the components.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery and Materialize, you can use the directive `:v-show="showAside"` or `:v-if="showAside"` with a property like `showAside` (in data) and handle the value with a click.

There is a very quick and cheap example: https://jsfiddle.net/nosferatu79/p85rw6xz/